# Background execution automatically stops after 3 minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process

I wanted upload photos as background task but background execution stops automatically after 3 minutes.

Code which I have done:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    //Stop upload call

    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];
}}
```

Comment: I already use it and it works perfectly till 3 minutes but after that it automatically stopped

Comment: enable background service by target - capabilities - Background Modes

Comment: Background fetch mode is already on

Comment: From where you are uploading? From stream or from file? If from stream or memory it might not work.

Comment: I checked dropbox app also , they face same problem what i have. its background photo uploading stops after 3 minutes.

Comment: @Feroz i did not get point. why its not working? do you have exact answer for this? if you have then please give me some link if possible

Comment: I upload my camera roll's photo to the server

Comment: Refer this link https://krumelur.me/2015/11/25/ios-background-transfer-what-about-uploads/

Comment: @Feroz i use file for uploading

Comment: Can you show your upload code?

Comment: In your link: i read The main gotcha here is that you’ll have to ensure that your app doesn’t get suspended while these standard request is running. You can use a UIApplication background task to do that, although it puts strict limits on how long you can run. Specifically:

When you move from the foreground to the background, the limit is currently 3 minutes.
When you are resumed in the background, the limit is 30 seconds.

Comment: You have to create an NSURLSession that is configured for background. If you do that the upload will continue even when you're app's 3 minutes of background time expire. You should start a background upload session, and then immidately end your background task.

Comment: Is this corect that the background execution limit have only 3 minutes running stage?

Comment: @SmarterSusheel, yes, that is by design.

Comment: @DuncanC strange i didn't find any link for this that apple by design it restrict background activity for only 3 minutes

Comment: Do you have apple link for this limit?

Comment: They don't document the time limit anywhere but they do say that there **is** a limit. If you look at the request for background time you see that a block is called when your background time is about to expire. I found the 3 minute limit based on experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

I found that iOS puts strict limits on how long you can run. Specifically:

When you move from the foreground to the background, the limit is currently 3 minutes.
When you are resumed in the background, the limit is 30 seconds.

Link referral : https://krumelur.me/2015/11/25/ios-background-transfer-what-about-uploads/

Thanks @feroz for providing the link.